# When i try to call a function in c++ it shows ambiguous erroe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When i tried to call a function in c++ ,it shows an ambiguous error,How can I solve this ?

[image]

Comment: code and error message should be as text in the question.

Comment: `using namspapce std;` 20 keystrokes to save 15 keystrokes for the price of surprising errors. Hm... perhaps reconsider if it is worth it

Answer (score 0):

Due to using the `using namespace std;` You have an intersection with the `std::greater`. This is the very lesson when you can understand that it is not advisable to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: I remove using namespace std; and use std:: in cout,in and endl and this solved my problem. Thank you sir